# How to determine google project name in python 3 appengine standard at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am doing some of the pre-work to port my python 2.7 appengine app to python 3.x. One piece that we use in our 2.7 app is detecting the project at run time, so we can set up different environments for different projects (testing, staging and production). I have not found a good way of doing this with the new python 3.x environment. Has anyone else had to do this?

What we're doing in our current app is:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
app_identity.get_application_id()
```

I'm kind of hoping there is a magic environment variable or something that will indicate what I'm project I'm running on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you use the request URL for this?

Comment: @gaefan I don't think so, we use a custom domain, so unless it's being rewritten somewhere along the way, I don't think that will work. Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On App Engine Standard you have Environment variables predefined, among them you have “GAE_APPLICATION”  which contains the ID of your App Engine application. You can see it on the following link: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables